# Form variables passed via jquery potential issue

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form for a mailing list script which I am trying to get working with ajax so the form can refresh without reloading. With the $.ajax part of the jquery commented out, the form variables are sent to the URL string.

> ?email=test%40address.com&sub=sub&submit=Submit+Form

My question is why is the submit=Submit+Form part there given that it isn't part of my "datastring" and will that be a problem when it comes to processing the actual PHP script?

Here is the form :

```
<form name="email_list" action="">

<p><strong>Your Email Address:</strong><br/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="40">
<input type="hidden" name="sub" id="sub" value="sub">

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" class="email_submit"></p>
</form>
```

and the JQuery

```
$(function() {    
$('.email_submit').submit(function() { 

var email = $("input#email").val();  
            if (name == "") { 
            $("input#email").focus();  
            return false;
        }  
var sub = $("input#sub").val();  
            if (name == "") {  
            $("input#sub").focus();  
            return false;
        }       

var dataString = '&email=' + email + '&sub=' + sub;

//alert (dataString);return false;  
/*$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "mailing_list_add2.php",  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function() {  
        $('#display_block')                      
        .hide()  
        .fadeIn(2500, function() {  
            $('#display_block');  
        }); 
    }  
}); 
return false; 
});*/

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the submit handler on the form, not on the button, even if is a submit button.

```
<form name="email_list" action="" id="my_form">
```

Update the javascript

```
$(function() {    
  $('#my_form').submit(function() { 
    ...
  });
});
```

To serialize all the inputs into a string you could use `$("#my_form").serialize()` which builds a string with all the inputs and their data ready for posting:

```
var dataString = $("#my_form").serialize();
```

Also note that having a `name` attribute defined for the submit input means that its value will be sent also in the form. If you don't need that, you can simply remove the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`Submit+Form` is the urlencoded version of `Submit Form`. The field `submit` is sent because you specify a `name` attribute to `<input type="submit" name="submit" ... />`. It will most likely not cause any problems for you (can't say without looking at your server-side code though).

Also, you really should specify a `method` attribute to your `<form>`. It seems to default to `GET`, which is why the form fields are added to the query string.

Comment: What would be a suitable method attribute? Does the ajax part of the form look like it will work? (if I can ask two questions ;)) The PHP code works by itself, I haven't tried it yet with the addition of the jquery.

Comment: @Andy it looks like you want to use `POST`. If you're using `$_GET` in PHP to access the data, then `method="GET"`, and with `$_POST` you'd do `method="POST"`. Also your JavaScript around `type: "POST"` should use the whichever method you choose

Comment: I tried adding the "method=" part with POST (because my PHP is using $_POST) and un-commented the $.ajax part in the jquery to test it. Not sure why but it didn't work. Whether that is the PHP side of things I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If you let your ajax POST happen, since you'r manually creating your `dataString` you won't see the Submit=, however when you let it submit 'normally' you see it, since the submit button is an input field with a value.

You won't encounter any issues with this. You can access the submit value just the same as any other POST value `$_POST['submit']` though I'm not sure why you'd want to.

Comment: You're welcome. If you consider this answered, I'd appreciate you mark it as such.